# Postgres query issue with price matching with two tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables, one is buy table and second is sell table.

**Buy Table**

```
id  price   qty  in_status  dt_added_at
1   10      15      1       2018-08-10 12:00:00+05:30
2   10      20      1       2018-08-10 13:00:00+05:30
3   12      15      1       2018-08-10 14:00:00+05:30
4   15      20      1       2018-08-10 15:00:00+05:30
```

**Sell Table**

```
id  price   qty  in_status  dt_added_at
1   15      20      1       2018-08-10 12:00:00+05:30
2   12      15      1       2018-08-10 13:00:00+05:30
3   10      15      1       2018-08-10 14:00:00+05:30
4   10      20      1       2018-08-10 15:00:00+05:30
5   10      15      1       2018-08-10 16:00:00+05:30
```

Applied query of price matching table

```
SELECT buy.*, sell.* FROM buy 
LEFT JOIN sell ON 
buy.price = sell.price AND buy.qty = sell.qty
WHERE buy.price = 10 AND buy.in_status = 1 AND sell.price = 10 AND 
sell.in_status = 1 
GROUP BY buy.id, sell.id, buy.dt_added_at, sell.dt_added_at 
ORDER BY buy.id, sell.id
```

**Actual Output**

```
id  price   qty  in_status  dt_added_at                   id    price   qty  in_status  dt_added_at
1   10      15      1       2018-08-10 12:00:00+05:30     3     10      15      1       2018-08-10 14:00:00+05:30
1   10      15      1       2018-08-10 12:00:00+05:30     5     10      15      1       2018-08-10 16:00:00+05:30
2   10      20      1       2018-08-10 13:00:00+05:30     4     10      20      1       2018-08-10 15:00:00+05:30
```

So here the 1st record of buy table is matched with the 3rd and 5th record of sell table but the 5th record should get omit because I need to implement FIFO and one buy record matched with one sell entry only and 2nd record of buy table is matched with the 4th record.

**Expected Output**

```
id  price   qty  in_status  dt_added_at                   id    price   qty  in_status  dt_added_at
1   10      15      1       2018-08-10 12:00:00+05:30     3     10      15      1       2018-08-10 14:00:00+05:30
2   10      20      1       2018-08-10 13:00:00+05:30     4     10      20      1       2018-08-10 15:00:00+05:30
```

You can see in below image.

[image]

**Edited at 18thAug2018 - Tried with this data and it not works**
As the entry of sell table is repeated.

```
CREATE TABLE Buy(
  id int,
  price int,
  qty int,
  in_status int,
  dt_added_at timestamp
);

insert into Buy values (1,10,15,1,'2018-08-10 12:00:00+05:30');
insert into Buy values (2,10,20,1,'2018-08-10 13:00:00+05:30');
insert into Buy values (3,10,15,1,'2018-08-10 14:00:00+05:30');
insert into Buy values (4,10,20,1,'2018-08-10 15:00:00+05:30');

CREATE TABLE sell(
  id int,
  price int,
  qty int,
  in_status int,
  dt_added_at timestamp
);

insert into sell values (1,15,20,1 ,'2018-08-10 12:00:00+05:30');
insert into sell values (2,12,15,1 ,'2018-08-10 13:00:00+05:30');
insert into sell values (3,10,15,1 ,'2018-08-10 14:00:00+05:30');
insert into sell values (4,10,20,1 ,'2018-08-10 15:00:00+05:30');
insert into sell values (5,10,15,1 ,'2018-08-10 16:00:00+05:30');
insert into sell values (6,10,20,1 ,'2018-08-10 17:00:00+05:30');
```

Comment: what about your 3   12      15      1       2018-08-10 14:00:00+05:30 this rows?

Comment: At a moment there is only one price matching between two tables so here I am only applying price is equal to 10.

Comment: Please refer the answer of d-shih below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to write a subquery with [Row_number](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-window.html) with `window function`  to make row_number by `price` and `qty`, then you can get `rn = 1` means the earlier
buy time by `dt_added_at`.

```
CREATE TABLE Buy(
  id int,
  price int,
  qty int,
  in_status int,
  dt_added_at timestamp
);


insert into Buy values (1,10,15,1,'2018-08-10 12:00:00+05:30');
insert into Buy values (2,10,20,1,'2018-08-10 13:00:00+05:30');
insert into Buy values (3,12,15,1,'2018-08-10 14:00:00+05:30');
insert into Buy values (4,15,20,1,'2018-08-10 15:00:00+05:30');

CREATE TABLE sell(
  id int,
  price int,
  qty int,
  in_status int,
  dt_added_at timestamp
);


insert into sell values (1,15,20,1 ,'2018-08-10 12:00:00+05:30');
insert into sell values (2,12,15,1 ,'2018-08-10 13:00:00+05:30');
insert into sell values (3,10,15,1 ,'2018-08-10 14:00:00+05:30');
insert into sell values (4,10,20,1 ,'2018-08-10 15:00:00+05:30');
insert into sell values (5,10,15,1 ,'2018-08-10 16:00:00+05:30');
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT buy.*, s.*
FROM buy 
LEFT JOIN (
    select s.*,Row_number() over(PARTITION BY price,qty ORDER BY dt_added_at) rn
    from sell s
) s ON 
buy.price = s.price AND buy.qty = s.qty and rn = 1
WHERE 
    buy.price = 10 
AND 
  buy.in_status = 1 
AND 
  s.price = 10 
AND 
  s.in_status = 1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/be13a/5/0)**:

```
| id | price | qty | in_status |          dt_added_at | id | price | qty | in_status |          dt_added_at | rn |
|----|-------|-----|-----------|----------------------|----|-------|-----|-----------|----------------------|----|
|  1 |    10 |  15 |         1 | 2018-08-10T12:00:00Z |  3 |    10 |  15 |         1 | 2018-08-10T14:00:00Z |  1 |
|  2 |    10 |  20 |         1 | 2018-08-10T13:00:00Z |  4 |    10 |  20 |         1 | 2018-08-10T15:00:00Z |  1 |
```

Comment: I have added query in above question and found that there is an issue with a query. Can you please revise the query and look into it?

Comment: Can you please look into my issue again? Thanks.

Comment: @Khushang Bhavnagarwala.  sorry reply so late I am busy in the morning and afternoon you can try to make row_number in buy table then get `rn=1` http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/5e205/14

Comment: @KhushangBhavnagarwala. Becasue you want to mapping rows which had been traded in first time.

Comment: @D-Shih.You are correct but one small problem here is that all entries of buy will match with sell table (1st buy->3rd sell, 2nd buy->4th sell, 3rd buy->5th sell, 4th buy->6th sell). But here only 1st and 2nd record of buy table is matched with 3rd and 4th record of sell table. Please refer this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/2485e/1. Thanks

Comment: @KhushangBhavnagarwala. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/2485e/3 just connect two tables with `rn` instead of `rn=1`

Comment: @D-Shih.Here date is not ascending. Can you please correct the solution? Thanks

Comment: @KhushangBhavnagarwala. What's your mean you mean your want to `order by` in the result set like this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/2485e/6?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178285/discussion-between-khushang-bhavnagarwala-and-d-shih).

Comment: @KhushangBhavnagarwala. I would select http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/2485e/6, because the `order by` in subquery that isn' any sense. the order will be Unstable in the main query.

Answer (score 2):

I would use a `DISTINCT ON`

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON ( s.price, s.qty) b.*, 
                                     s.* 
FROM   buy b 
       LEFT JOIN sell s 
              ON b.price = s.price 
                 AND b.qty = s.qty 
WHERE  b.price = 10 
       AND b.in_status = 1 
       AND s.price = 10 
       AND s.in_status = 1 
ORDER  BY s.price, 
          s.qty, 
          s.dt_added_at
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/d9a4b/11)

Answer (score 0):

Aggregate function min() help to you to pick FIFO based data

```
 select t.*,s1.* from 
   (
    select b.id,b.dt_added_at,
     s.price,s.qty, min(s.dt_added_at) as sdt_added_at from 
     Buy b inner join 
   sell s on 
    b.price = s.price AND b.qty = s.qty
    where s.in_status = 1 and b.price=10
    group by  s.price,s.qty,b.id,b.dt_added_at
  ) t
  left join sell s1 on t.sdt_added_at =s1.dt_added_at
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/b543e3/9

```
id  dt_added_at           price qty sdt_added_at           id price qty in_status   dt_added_at
1   2018-08-10T12:00:00Z    10  15  2018-08-10T14:00:00Z    3   10  15  1   2018-08-10T14:00:00Z
2   2018-08-10T13:00:00Z    10  20  2018-08-10T15:00:00Z    4   10  20  1   2018-08-10T15:00:00Z
```